# ##[error]The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have created a build and release pipeline in Azure DevOps, and I have been trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core Website on my local machine, but I am getting this error:

"The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system."

Does this mean it's impossible to deploy to IIS on a client-based operating system, or, do I need to fix something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have IIS enabled in "Windows Features" dialog, that you can find in Control Panel > Turn Windows Features On and Off.